# How to prevent pixels from blending when enlarging images in ImageViews Android

Tags: android, pixel

I want to use 16x16 images and blow them up without the pixels blending in Android. I understand it will be very pixel-looking (that's what I want). How can I enlarge an image while keeping the pixel look intact?

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that before you import the image, it is already the size that you wanted so that if you use it on your image view, the quality of image will stay the same.

Comment: Yes I understand that would work. But I really just want in to be a 16x16 image then be able to blow it up with image view while keeping the pixel-look intact. I will be saving a bunch of these, therefore I don't what to waste file space on 512x512 images that have the same look as the 16x16.

Comment: Well if that's the case, you have to do that. There's no way you can enlarge a picture without destroying its quality. Import two pictures then.

Answer (score 0):

i have had the same problem

[how to load image as pixel image in android java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63555990/how-to-load-image-as-pixel-image-in-android-java/63561676#63561676)

here is how i solved it

width of the pixel square =
width of the screen / num of pixels