# how to load image as pixel image in android java?

Tags: java, android, image, bitmap, pixel

i want to creat an android app
that shows all pixels of an image but when i zoom color of the corners of the pixels blend with other pixels around it i want pixels to show their color perfectly in their squares
( like pixel art or ms paint when you zoom it)
i tried drawing a rectangle on canvas and drawing a bitmap 1×1
with color what i want  but it blends

here is a picture and code
upper pic 4×4 what it creates
lower pic what i want

```
try{   
 //creating bitmap from other for background

 bt2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(bt,i2,i3,i,i);

}

Canvas c=new Canvas(bt2);
c.drawColor(Color.argb(255,255,255,255));

//creating 1×1 image
Bitmap bt3 = Bitmap.createBitmap(bt,0,0,1,  1  );
//blue color to draw for pixel looking

Canvas c2 =new Canvas(bt3);
c2.drawColor(Color.argb(255,0,0,255));


int w=bt2.getWidth();
int h= bt2.getHeight();

//geting pixels so i would use it

btpixels=new int [w*h];
bt2.getPixels(btpixels,
   0,w,0,0,w,h );
   
int j =0;
Paint paint =new Paint();

for(j=0;j<w;j++)
{

paint.setARGB(255,0,255,0);
//drawing blue bitmap on bt2

c.drawBitmap(bt3,j,j,paint) ;

//paint.setColor( btpixels[j]);

 /*  c.drawRect(
   (float)i-1,     
   (float) i-1, 
   (float)i,
   (float)i,
 paint );  */
 
 }
img.setImageBitmap( bt2 );

}catch(IllegalArgumentException e){  }
```

[image]

Comment: cant find how to edit but upper pic is 2×2.

Answer (score 0):

i understood how to stop pixels from blending. I was using 2×2 image on the screen 300ppi . If i want to show 1 pixel per inch i should use pixel bitmap(here bt3) width as 300
best would be
width of the pixel square =
width of the screen / num of pixels